# Is there a way to quickly encase a list of words with "quotation marks"

Tags: r, string

I am trying to create a vector of words in R, but have a huge list of words, so manually writing `"word1", "word2", ..., "word100"` would be very tedious.

Given I have the list of words comma separated, is there a way to quickly encase them with quotation marks?

For instance I have:

`words = c(apple,bannana,cat,...,dolphin)`

but I want

`words = c("apple","bannana","cat",...,"dolphin")`.

Comment: Your code `words = c(apple,bannana,cat,...,dolphin)` is not clear.  It wouldn't work on the R unless you already created those objects.  Did you created those objects earlier?

Comment: The solution to your problem depends upon the input.  Is it just that you have a a line of code `words = c(apple,bannana,cat)` that forgot to add the string

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - you're right, words = c(apple, banana,...) doesn't exist. All I mean is that in my clipboard I have apple, banana, cat, ..., dolphin and was wondering if there were a quick way to apply the change so I can get the final line: words = `c("apple","bannana","cat",...,"dolphin")`

Comment: I updated the post based on your comments.  Hopefiully, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to create a character vector from an expression

```
words <-  scan(text = trimws(str1, whitespace = ".*\\(|\\)"),
    what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- "words = c(apple,bannana,cat)"
```

Comment: sorry, word1,word2,..., was just a generic example.

Comment: thank you, this worked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the list on your clipboard:

```
wordlist <- unname(unlist(read.csv(file="clipboard", header=FALSE))) # Windows
wordlist <- unname(unlist(read.csv(pipe("pbpaste"), header=FALSE))) $ MacOs
wordlist
# [1] "apple"   "bannana" "cat"     "dolphin"
```

You may get a warning message if there is no line return at the end of the clipboard listing, but you can ignore it.